# Printer stops pinging after 3 minutes from IPSEC remote side. Continues from local side

Tags: ipsec, ping, site-to-site-vpn, printer, icmp

I have a very strange issue that I have come across twice now. It is making me go cross-eyed.

We have two sites, one runs our server infrastructure and the other hosts end-users. There is an IPSEC tunnel established between StrongSWAN and Cisco ASA (v. 9.8.1). Connectivity is over a 100Mbps AT&T Fiber and Blanded Colo Bandwidth.

All devices and services are working well and we do not drop pings from almost all equipment. Pinging access points and thin clients works well.

One printer, an HP 401N LaserJet Printer will ping for 3 minutes (185 - 205 pings), and then stop (pinging from the remote side). Locally, pinging and services continue to work. All services become inaccessible from the remote side. The only way to restore connectivity is to change network settings (we have been setting the gateway to .2, then back to .1), or rebooting the printer.

The strange part is, its only the remote side that looses connectivity, and it only happens after a few minutes.

A similar issue came up a few months ago, but that was a different make / model printer, was over a decade old, and we determined it was too old to troubleshoot and replaced the printer. We have other printers that work just fine. It is only this printer that is affected.

We have tried disabling IPv6, turning off all ACLs on the printer's administrative page, and maintaining a constant pint (both from local and remote). 3 minutes does not correspond to the tunnel's re-keying timer, or anything else we can think of.

Comment: Is there a firewall between these machines? Sounds like your traffic might be getting blocked after a period of time to mitigate ping attacks.

Comment: The ASA is the only firewall, one end of the tunnel. I would agree with you, but why just the one printer? I have checked the running config and I can't see anything related to that, and nothing shows up in the logs pertaining to blocking the pings. Other printers continue to ping for hours after.

Comment: Maybe that one printer has a really messed up networking stack. Is it on ancient firmware?

Comment: We updated the firmware just now. Initial tests seem good. Doesn't make sense to me why a firmware problem would stop working for routed packets vs local packets. Anyway, seems OK now.